# how to stop minification on release build?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I am creating an MVC4 application.  I am using bundling, the debug version works great, but when I publish the application I am getting errors.

Does anyone know how to turn minification off so that it just includes the full version of the js files?

Thanks

Comment: `but when I publish the application I am getting errors.` You think the exact error message isn't important enough to post?

Comment: no because I know the errors are due to the minified javacsript file.  And the errors is not the question I asked.  I thought I asked a pretty straight forward question, but I guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EnableOptimizations = false` will turn off both bundling and minification.